# visualsvn - repository server hosting

Tags: svn, version-control, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I am just having a look into VisualSVN but have no experience with version control so please apologize my stupid question.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 / 2010 and understand that I require a Subversion server (i.e. 'repository server'). I also understand that there is a VisualSVN Server but the free version might be too restrictive (or is it not?). So I read that you can use google code as 'repository server'. Did someone do this? Is it recommended? Is it safe? What alternatives exist?

Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Many thanks!

Christian

Comment: The free version is definitely not restrictive. Yes, it lacks some goodies, but then read about what that is before concluding you can't use it, because you most probably can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also understand that there is a visualsvn server but the free version might be too restrictive (or is it not?)

Not really. I've been working happily with VisualSVN's free version for a long time.

The main additional features of the paid version are [advanced authentication, access logging and remote administration.](http://visualsvn.com/server/licensing/) For most small teams, those are expendable options.

You can also work with local, filesystem-based repositories, but in a multi-user environment, you're much better and easier off with a proper SVN server.

Comment: I have a server which I can administrate remotely. Could I 'just' install it there? Is the basic windows authentication secure enough?

Comment: @csetzkorn I don't know about basic windows auth and its intricacies, I use SVN's built-in authentication and I'm quite happy. You should be able to install it easily on a remote server through RDP